# Security Risks of catch-all email address

Tags: security, email, spam

What additional security issues does an MTA and email client face if a catch-all email address is setup on an sub-domain (that isn't published/publicly listed anywhere) compared with setting up individual email forwarders to the same address (as needed). Stakeholders are administrator of MTA and email user.

Comment: What security risks do you envision?

Comment: Spam is probably the main one.

Comment: Spam is not really a security risk.

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit using proper risk assessment language: what vulnerabilities does such a configuration cause and what are the risks of those vulnerabilities being exploited?

Comment: I think the real question is: how secure is your MTA and how "secure" are the users and/or applications that will be consuming mail sent to this address.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: Then you need to drastically re-work your question. Please edit it to clarify what you're really asking.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, none.

I don't know why you'd want to set up a spam collector, but that's really all a catch-all email address will do.  No security risk, so long as you have an anti-spam/email security solution in place and/or the users know better than to open `nakedcoedsxxx.zip.exe` and the like.

Comment: One reason to have a catch-all address is to ensure the system doesn't bounce invalid addresses, such as those randomly generated addresses used by spam systems. Whether or not that has a real benefit for reducing spam is very open to argument.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers  Yeah, not the method I'd use to suppress bounces to invalid addresses, but that would be a use for a catch-all address.

Comment: As I said, open to argument. Also not the method I would use but certainly one I've seen promoted for that purpose. It is the only way to avoid bounces while strictly adhering to the RFCs, which demand a bounce for invalid addresses.

Comment: The email security solution doesn't make it a higher or lower risk. It only exposes a bigger probability of catching an unsolicited mail. A virus to one address or a catch-all-address in both cases requires a user to just delete it.